# Can INTERACTIVE applications (for offline usage) be made in HTML5 like in Flash (using Actionscript)?

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, flash-cs4, interactive

My plan was to create an interactive map thingy using .swf file that I'd make in Flash CS4 and perhaps incorporate it in my Visual C++ application, add some components and make an .exe file out of it. I obtained the platform from Adobe. My further plan was to get familiar with all the tools, learn ActionScript 3.0 and pick up some stuff from Visual C++ 2010 that I'll need along the way.

Later I was browsing the Web and read that Flash is getting pretty old and that everything is going towards HTML5, described as the latest HTML standard that uses CSS and some other stuff + JavaScript.

My questions are: Can I create my application like above described? 
Can you make these kind of interactive applications (for offline usage) in HTML5? 
If so, should I switch to it and what programming languages would I be obligated to learn? JavaScript? HTML syntax?

I am familiar only with the basics of C++ programming and I want to learn everything else I'll be using for my project along the way. I also apologize if my English is terrible, or if my question is badly put together.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the node-webkit project. In my opinion this is very promising: https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit